# Definition of a compact set correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I am suspicious about the following definition of a compact set:

Let X bei a normed vector space and $M\subset X$. M ist called compact, if every sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in M$ has a convergent subsequence (with limes in M).

Doesn't there need to be something like a bounded sequence?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean normed vector space? Also what do you mean by restricted? Do you mean bounded?

Comment: I corrected it sorry - I'm not used to the English words :)

Comment: No problem. So why are you suspicious? From the definition is follows that every such sequence must be bounded and that is indeed what we want. Since a compact set should be bounded and closed.

Comment: I was just wondering because in $\mathbb{R}$ for example the condition is that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence and it seemed to me that this property of $\mathbb{R}$ is what one is aming for when it comes to normed vector spaces.

Comment: But $\mathbb{R}$ is not a compact set and it really shouldn't be. However, every bounded and closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is compact. (All assuming you are using the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: If every sequence *must* have a convergent subsequence, then it will follow as a consequence that the sequence is bounded.  So you don't need to state it.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

Actually, the boundedness is a consequence of the compactness of the set : a compact set in a metric space is always closed and bounded (and the converse is true iff the dimension is finite).